# Multiple file upload using busboy (nodejs) and issue related response object

Tags: node.js, busboy

I am using busboy module to upload files. It works very well for one file. However it throws following error when I tried to upload the multiple file.

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent
```

I know why its throwing error, but I am not able to figure out the solution. Following is my code snippet.

```
  exports.uploadFile = function (req, res) {
     console.log('Calling uploadFile inside FileUploadService');
     var fstream;
     req.pipe(req.busboy);

     req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldName, file, fileName) {
         // Get folderGuid
         var folderGuid = req.params.folderGuid;
         //Get folderName
         var folderName = req.query.folderName;
         //path of file contents
         var directoryPath = fileRepositoryPath + "/" + folderGuid+"/"+folderName;
         //Get location
         var filePath = directoryPath + "/" + fileName;
         log.debug("inside FileUploadService ::: uploadFile >> folderGuid:  " + folderGuid + ", directoryPath : " + directoryPath + ", filePath : " + filePath);
         //Create directory
         nodefs.mkdir(directoryPath, 0777, true, function (err) {
             if (err) {
                 log.error({err: err}, 'Error while creating recurrisve directory');
             } else {
                 log.debug('inside FileUploadService ::: uploadFile >> Directory created');
             }
             //Write object on file system
             fstream = nodefs.createWriteStream(filePath);
             file.pipe(fstream);
             fstream.on('close', function (err) {

                 if (!err) {
                     var relativePath = "/" + folderGuid + "/" + fileName;
                     log.info('Successfully uploaded file relativePath >> '+relativePath); 
                     res.status(constants.HTTP_CODE_OK);
                     res.json({"relativePath": relativePath});
                 } else {
                     log.error({err: err}, 'Failed to upload file');
                     res.status(constants.HTTP_CODE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                     res.json({error: err});
                 }
             });

         });
     });

 };
```

I know following line of code is throwing error, this is because in case of multiple files, this line of code is executed twice which cause the error.

```
 res.status(constants.HTTP_CODE_OK);
 res.json({"relativePath": relativePath});
```

How can I track multiple event of "`req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldName, file, fileName)`" so that once all file processing is finished then only I should send the response?

Please help.

Comment: Have you found a solution so far? I face the same problem..

Comment: i have the same issue. :(

Answer (score 1):

Busboy handles one file at a time so according to your code response is sent after one file streaming completion.
Now when next file streaming completion, response is already sent therefore you are getting this error.

Try sending response after all files are done.

```
  req.busboy.on('finish', function() {
    res.status(constants.HTTP_CODE_OK);
    res.json({"relativePath": relativePath});
  });
```

or try as in this question's answer: [busboy-connect fires on finish before the end of save file (node.js , express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009583/busboy-connect-fires-on-finish-before-the-end-of-save-file-node-js-express?rq=1)

Comment: Yes Indeed... It will work. And Busboy called finish only one time once all operation completes.

Answer (score 0):

You can change syntax, include "req.pipe(req.busboy);" after "req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldName, file, fileName) {})"